# How to share file access between some processes using Mutex?

Tags: c#, file, mutex

I have a simple class for copying files from one directory to another. Also, I need to get a file checksum after copying. The copying method may be called by many instances, for example, 5 processes are copying one file to 5 different directories in parallel, so when some processes try to get checksum, I get an IO exception.

So I've tried to tell each process to wait until the source file is unlocked:

```
bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Such a decision works, but only if I call `Thread.Sleep(10)` in while loop(in getting checksum method for waiting), otherwise I get the same error.

```
while (IsFileLocked(fi))
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

So I see, that it's a very bad solution.
Now I try to use Mutex:

```
string GetFileHash(string path)
{
    string hashValue = null;

    using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);

        try
        {
            mutexObj.WaitOne();

            using (FileStream fileStream = fi.Open(FileMode.Open))
            {
                fileStream.Position = 0;
                hashValue = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(sha256.ComputeHash(fileStream));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"GHM:I/O Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"GHM:Access Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            mutexObj.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
    
    return hashValue;
}
```

But that doesn't work. I think, that the problem is in different Mutex instances in 5 independent processes.

So, tell me, please, how to solve this? Is there a way to declare global mutex?

Comment: just use mutexObj=new Mutex(false, path)

Comment: If you are only copying the file, why not use open it with `FileShare.Read` ? That should allow the same file to be read by multiple processes.

Comment: @JonasH, thank you, that helped)) So I don't need using Mutex))

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev, thank you, too, I will remember it in future